# Sending files one-by-one at a time using Java

Tags: java, file-io

I am using java for my server side application and phonegap for my client side.i need to transfer huge image files when user login to my application.

I convert those image files to base64 format and put it into json object.when i send this json object to client side i am  getting java out of memory error.

How to send those image files one by one in a single request since sending all files at a time causes java memory out of error.pl help me.

Here is my code:

```
File folderName = new File(processingFolder+"/"+f1[i].getName());
File[] folderFiles= folderName.listFiles();

for(int m=0;m<folderFiles.length;m++)
{
 System.out.println("folderFiles are:"+folderFiles[m]);
 String s1 = new String();
 File readfile = new File(folderFiles[m].toString());
 System.out.println(readfile.exists() + "!!");

 FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(readfile);
 ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

 byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
 try {
     for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1;) {
         bos.write(buf, 0, readNum); 
         //no doubt here is 0
         /*Writes len bytes from the specified byte array starting at offset 
         off to this byte array output stream.*/
     }
 }


 catch (IOException ex) {
 }
 byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();

 String result2 = Base64.encode( bytes );
 json1.put(folderFiles[m].getName(), result2);
```

Comment: I dont know phonegap. Do you think you could create session that will maintain number of already send files and make you client to request another file, when previous has been received by client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution for my question.
 i have send all the file names to the client side in json format. by looping the files names in the client side i send request to server and get a single file for each request. then i again write that file in my client side.